# A Rails' javascript_include_tag equivalent for Struts?

Tags: java, tags, struts

How can I emulate the `javascript_include_tag` (from Rails) for a Struts 1 application?

Something like:

```
<%= includeJS('jquery', 'application', 'blah1', 'blah2', ...) %>
```

In the JSP would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a similar result to Rails' `javascript_include_tag` by using a custom JSP tag (Struts has nothing similar but it [is not that difficult to create one yourself](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tutorial/TagLibrariesTOC.html)).

A tag like the following should do the trick:

```
<my:includeJS sources="jquery, application, blah1, blah2" />
```

Your tag will have a string attribute (named `sources` in the example above) that receives a comma delimited list of script names. Once in your tag handler, you split the names by the comma and use them to create the HTML `<script>` tags:

```
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/blah1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/blah2.js"></script>
```